# How do I get Windows 7 To Recognize a newly installed RAID 5 volume?

Tags: windows-7, raid, raid-5

I had a previously running Windows 7 (64 bit) system.  I added 3 new 1TB Seagate drives that I set up as a RAID 5 volume.  I have a Gigabyte GA-P55M-UD2 motherboard.  I installed the drives, set up the BIOS and configured the three drives as a RAID volume through the RAID setup utility that was accessed via Ctrl-I while the system was booting.  I rebooted the system and could see the drives during the boot sequence.  However, when Windows 7 was starting I got an error (quick blue screen) and then Windows tried to repair itself with no success.  Do I need to install RAID drivers in Windows?  How do I do it if Windows won't boot?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.  It turns out that I had to re-install Windows in order to get the RAID drivers installed.  While I re-formatted all of the drives and re-installed Windows, I think I probably could have done a "non-destructive" re-installation of Windows.  In any case, Windows must be re-installed to go from non-RAID to enabling RAID on the motherboard even if the volume containing Windows is not in a RAID volume itself.